# How to create user login and registration form using Access

Tags: c#

I need to create a user login and registration form using database with Visual studio c# and Access application. There are examples on the internet using only sql. How can I do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Good old OleDbConnection!

Comment: Why MSAccess of all things? All the _cool kids_ have been using SQLite for in-proc databases for most of the past decade now (even Microsoft), or using Postgres...

Comment: I need to do it with Access. I can create a user login form but not a registration form.

Comment: Whatever you don't, don't store the password in Access in plain-text. Make sure to **salt and hash** (not encrypt, encryption is different) it first. When logging in, you do same thing with the attempted password, and then only compare the hashes. This is one of those things that's too important to do wrong, _even for learning/proof of concept projects_.

Comment: I tried to do it using SQL, but I got 15 errors.

Comment: Access is still SQL, so you're gonna have to work through them